# Raspberry real time clock with Ubuntu

Tags: python, raspberrypi

I'm trying to get the sb components USB RTC for Raspberry Pi working with my Raspberry running Ubuntu. It works when I use it with Raspberrian, but when I try it with Ubuntu test.py and Set_Time.py give the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/USB-RTC/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    bus = SMBus.SMBus()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyMCP2221A/SMBus.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.mcp2221 = PyMCP2221A.PyMCP2221A(VID,PID,devnum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyMCP2221A/PyMCP2221A.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.mcp2221a.open_path(hid.enumerate(VID, PID)[devnum]["path"])
  File "hid.pyx", line 142, in hid.device.open_path
OSError: open failed
```

I've been searching for several hours and trying everything I can find but I'm not having any luck.

Here's the RTC;
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B094R8H9B1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094R8H9B1)

---

Thank you for the reply. It's a Raspberry Pi 4. Ubuntu 18.4 and Xfce 4.12.

Here are the contents of those Python files;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#from PyMCP2221A import SMBus
from PyMCP2221A import SMBus

import time
 
address = 0x68  #i2c address of DS3231
register = 0x00
CONV = 32


#sec min hour week day month year
NowTime = [0x00,0x00,0x18,0x04,0x12,0x08,0x15]  #Edit this line to set RTC Date and Time

w  = ["SUN","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"];

#/dev/i2c-1
bus = SMBus.SMBus()
def ds3231SetTime():
    #bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,register,NowTime)
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x00, NowTime[0]) # set seconds and start clock
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x01, NowTime[1]) # set minutes
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x02, NowTime[2]) # set hours in 24 hour mode
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x03, NowTime[3]) # set day of week
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x04, NowTime[4]) # set date
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x05, NowTime[5]) # set month
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x06, NowTime[6]) # set year - last 2 digits
 
def ds3231ReadTime():
    return bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,register,7);

# Force a conversion and wait until it completes
def convTemp(address):
    byte_control = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x0E)
    if byte_control&CONV == 0:
        bus.write_byte_data(address, 0x0E, byte_control|CONV)
    byte_control = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x0E)
    while byte_control&CONV != 0:
        #time.sleep(1)
        byte_control = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x0E)
    return True

# Get temperature in degrees C
def getTemp(address):
    convTemp(address)
    byte_tmsb = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x11)
    byte_tlsb = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x12)
    tinteger = (byte_tmsb & 0x7f) + ((byte_tmsb & 0x80) >> 7) * -2**8
    tdecimal = (byte_tmsb >> 7) * 2**(-1) + ((byte_tmsb & 0x40) >> 6) * 2**(-2)
    return tinteger + tdecimal
 
ds3231SetTime()
while 1:
    t = ds3231ReadTime()
    t[0] = t[0]&0x7F  #sec
    t[1] = t[1]&0x7F  #min
    t[2] = t[2]&0x3F  #hour
    t[3] = t[3]&0x07  #week
    t[4] = t[4]&0x3F  #day
    t[5] = t[5]&0x1F  #month
    print("20%x/%x/%x %x:%x:%x  %s" %(t[6],t[5],t[4],t[2],t[1],t[0],w[t[3]-1]))
    time.sleep(1)

    '''Celsius = getTemp(address)
    Fahrenheit = 9.0/5.0 * Celsius + 32
    print (Fahrenheit, "*F /", Celsius, "*C")
    time.sleep(1)'''
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyMCP2221A import SMBus

import time
import os
 
address = 0x68
register = 0x00
CONV = 32


#sec min hour week day month year
NowTime = [0x00,0x00,0x18,0x04,0x12,0x08,0x15]  #Edit this line to set RTC Date and Time

w  = ["SUN","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"];

#/dev/i2c-1
bus = SMBus.SMBus()
def ds3231SetTime():
    #bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,register,NowTime)
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x00, NowTime[0]) # set seconds and start clock
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x01, NowTime[1]) # set minutes
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x02, NowTime[2]) # set hours in 24 hour mode
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x03, NowTime[3]) # set day of week
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x04, NowTime[4]) # set date
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x05, NowTime[5]) # set month
    bus.write_byte_data(0x68, 0x06, NowTime[6]) # set year - last 2 digits
 
def ds3231ReadTime():
    return bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,register,7);

# Force a conversion and wait until it completes
def convTemp(address):
    byte_control = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x0E)
    if byte_control&CONV == 0:
        bus.write_byte_data(address, 0x0E, byte_control|CONV)
    byte_control = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x0E)
    while byte_control&CONV != 0:
        #time.sleep(1)
        byte_control = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x0E)
    return True

# Get temperature in degrees C
def getTemp(address):
    convTemp(address)
    byte_tmsb = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x11)
    byte_tlsb = bus.read_byte_data(address,0x12)
    tinteger = (byte_tmsb & 0x7f) + ((byte_tmsb & 0x80) >> 7) * -2**8
    tdecimal = (byte_tmsb >> 7) * 2**(-1) + ((byte_tmsb & 0x40) >> 6) * 2**(-2)
    return tinteger + tdecimal
 
ds3231SetTime()
while 1:
    t = ds3231ReadTime()
    t[0] = t[0]&0x7F  #sec
    t[1] = t[1]&0x7F  #min
    t[2] = t[2]&0x3F  #hour
    t[3] = t[3]&0x07  #week
    t[4] = t[4]&0x3F  #day
    t[5] = t[5]&0x1F  #month
    print('20%x/%x/%x %x:%x:%x  %s' %(t[6],t[5],t[4],t[2],t[1],t[0],w[t[3]-1]))
    time.sleep(1)

    '''year = '20%x' %(t[6])
    month = '%x' %(t[5])
    day = '%x' %(t[4])

    hour = '%x' %(t[2])
    minute = '%x' %(t[1])
    sec = '%x' %(t[0])

    date_str=year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day
    time_str=hour +":"+ minute +":"+ sec


    data= ('\''+date_str +" "+ time_str+'\'')
    

    dd=os.system("sudo date -s "+data)
    #print(dd)'''
```

Comment: can we see the *contents* of test.py and Set_Time.py ??

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! How can I tell if it's a stack age issue? Can you see the additional info that I posted?